# Effect of cellular phone towers on human health

Tags: cancer, literature, health

We live in world of mobiles, tablets, PCs and other electronic gadgets. We are continuously exposed to radio frequencies and other [cellular frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_frequencies). Generally, all of these waves are very low energy / long wavelength (which makes them [non-inonizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-ionizing_radiation)). This makes them less probable agents to cause any health problems.

I have been searching for potential effect of cellular phone towers on human health. Towers will emit large number of such waves due to our daily usage of electronic devices. The International Agency for Research on Cancer (IARC) has [reported](http://www.cancer.org/cancer/cancercauses/othercarcinogens/athome/cellular-phone-towers) cumulative radiofrequencies are categorized as class 2B (*possibly carcinogenic to humans*). Does this mean people living near cellular phone towers are more prone to health hazards?

I was searching for scientific reports to support or deny any claim made here. I checked the [FDA](http://www.fda.gov/Radiation-EmittingProducts/RadiationEmittingProductsandProcedures/HomeBusinessandEntertainment/CellPhones/default.htm) website for guidelines:

> Under the law, FDA does not review the safety of radiation-emitting consumer products such as cell phones and similar wireless devices before they can be sold, as it does with new drugs or medical devices.... FDA shares regulatory responsibilities for cell phones with the Federal Communications Commission (FCC)

However, the [FCC](http://The%20FDA,%20which%20has%20primary%20jurisdiction%20for%20investigating%20mobile%20phone%20safety,%20has%20stated%20that%20it%20cannot%20rule%20out%20the%20possibility%20of%20risk) guidelines state:

> The FDA, which has primary jurisdiction for investigating mobile phone safety, has stated that it cannot rule out the possibility of risk

And there are lot of other links to other organizations. I couldn't find any citing of scientific paper. This, again, made me confused as to whether cellular phone towers are safe for people living around them? How does the 'non-thermal' effect of this radiation work? There are few reports (like [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20015314) and [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12759101)) which I found but they didn't seem convincing.

Comment: I suggest using Google scholar search to find a review paper which will summarise studies done in the area before. If you want to save time you can answer your question by reading the abstract and the conclusion. Good luck!

Comment: Well.. I don't know why you tagged this question with [tag:cancer]. Microwaves can have some harmful effects but carcinogenesis is not one of them. MW do not have enough energy to cause electronic transitions that can cause DNA damage or produce free radicals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/36394/3340

Comment: @WYSIWYG I used cancer tag because only health hazard I was able to find with reliable source is "possibly carcinogenic" remark from IARC (as mentioned in question). Also I know that companies requires NOC (No objection certificate) from radiologist or radio oncologist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/39422/3340 as well

Comment: C'mon, how is that duplicate? There discussion is about different kinds of radiations.